# How can I keep an app always running?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, background-process

I have started using CM Security on my new phone which runs Android 6.0. I use the Applock feature, but the problem is it doesn't work because... just as I kill the window from my recent apps, CM Security also stops running in the background and as a result the password protection doesn't work.

So I was looking for a way to keep the app always running on the background.

P.S: My phone is not rooted.

Comment: If I may go off-topic... uninstall CM Security presto. I was one of their moderators and core members, and I myself resigned. That app will only spam you with ads whilst grabbing data and possibly uploading it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,
I've been using DoMobile Applock, but when that stopped working, I tried CM

Answer (score 1):

The app [Wake Lock Revamp - Power Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wldonate) 
helps to keep apps running in the background.

Comment: It would help if you provide instructions to use this app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try another security software like *Avast*, *AVG*. For example I have system (*KitKat*) with built in deamon *App Permission Manager* so it's never stop.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and see if it helps